# What's wrong with URLClassLoader when working with directories?

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
File folder = /* the folder with a.txt file */
final URL[] urls = new URL[] {
  folder.toURI().toURL()
};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
assertThat(loader.getResource("/a.txt"), is(notNullValue()));
```

Doesn't work. `getResource()` returns `NULL`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the resource names are always relative to the classpath you constructed the class loader with. You can't use an absolute name (that is, one that starts with `/`).

Comment: what should I use instead of `"/a.txt"`?

Comment: Only you can answer that. What is your file called? A reasonable guess would be `"a.txt"`, though. What are you trying to achieve with the slash?